# C++ Functions: Reading until End of File- Finding error in code

Tags: c++, function, loops

1. Write a program that opes a file and reads until the end of line using a loop.
2. Write a value returning function that calculates the salary as hours worked times hourly rate

   - the file input.txt contains: last name, hours worked, hourly rate.
   - Ex: Smith 80 15.00
3. Open the file and check the file state, exiting the program if the file fails to open.
4. Read the data in a loop and call the function to calculate the salary
5. After the function call output the salary calculated.

This is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    float DetermineSalary(ifstream& inFile, float hoursWorked, float 
    hourlyRate);
    int main (){
        ifstream inFile;
        inFile.open("input.txt");//opening file
        string name;
        float hoursWorked, hourlyRate;
        float salary;
        inFile >> name >> hoursWorked >> hourlyRate; //priming read

     while(inFile){
         inFile >> name >> hoursWorked >> hourlyRate;
         DetermineSalary(inFile, hoursWorked, hourlyRate);
         cout << "The salary for " << name << "is: $"  << salary << endl;
     }
    if (!inFile){
         cout << "Error opening file." << endl;
         return 1;
     }
  }
float DetermineSalary(ifstream& inFile, float hoursWorked, float hourlyRate){
    string name;
    float salary;

     getline(inFile, hoursWorked);
     getline(inFile, hourlyRate);
     getline(inFile, name);
     while(inFile){
         salary = hoursWorked * hourlyRate;
     }
}
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with this. Would love if anyone can point me in the right direction and explain what is wrong or what i can improve?

Thanks!!

Comment: you haven't identified the problem with your current code. What is currently doing VS what it should. We are volunteers, so we expect a bit more than "my homework doesn't work please debug"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared salary variable inside Your function DetermineSalary.  Every function call, data gets stored in variable inside function, not the salary variable declared in main. Delete salary variable inside function and it should work.

Comment: Thank you!! I passed it in by value in my function DetermineSalary.

Comment: This is a good way :)
Please mark answer as correct so the thread can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I have re-write your code. Please see your mistakes in below code. Try with this and let me know if you need any more help.

```
//using namespace std;
float DetermineSalary( float hoursWorked, float  hourlyRate);
int main (){
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("input.txt");//opening file
    if (!inFile){
         std::cout << "Error opening file." << std::endl;
         return 1;
    }
    std::string name;
    std::string hW, hR;
    float hoursWorked = 0, hourlyRate = 0;
    float salary;
    //inFile >> name >> hoursWorked >> hourlyRate; //priming read you dont need this line

    while(inFile >> name >> hW >> hR){
       hoursWorked = ::atof(hW.c_str());
       hourlyRate = ::atof(hR.c_str());
       salary = DetermineSalary(hoursWorked, hourlyRate);
       std::cout << "The salary for " << name << "is: $"  << salary << std::endl;
    }
}

float DetermineSalary(float hoursWorked, float hourlyRate){
  return (hoursWorked + hourlyRate);
}
```